# validate ConfigurationProperties mapping

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Is there a way to validate application.properties (or yml) if the properties match Java bean that it is mapped to via @ConfigurationProperties - so that if there is a typo in an attribute, exception will be thrown?

I tried using @Validated but it works only if every property has @NotNull annotation - but this is not exactly what I want to achieve... there may be some nullable properties in the config and I still want to "validate" them

I just spent 2 hours debugging an issue and I found out, the problem is that I misspelled an attribute name
e.g. application.yml

```
 property1: 1
 properrrrrty2: 2
```

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties
public class AppConfig {
    private String property1;     
    private String property2; // <--- this property does not match due to typo in application.yml
}
```

Comment: It sounds like you want a spellchecker for you application.properties file. It is totally possible even though sounds like a complete overkill for the task. Read all the properties defined in a file then using reflection iterate through the fields and see if some of your properties don’t exist in class under the same name.

Comment: A decent IDE should highlight `properrrrrty2` as unrecognized. Are you using one?

Answer (score 0):

**A)**

If you want to be sure that always a property exists then use `@Validated` with `@NotNull` for that property. `@NotNull` will complain if it does not find that property. You can still have the property there with an empty value if that is what you mean with nullable properties and `NotNull` will not complain.

You can't say I want it to be able to be nullable but also the validator should complain when that property is null.

So to sum things up.

`@NotEmpty` property must exist and also not have an empty value

`@NotNull` property must just exist. It does not care if it exists with an empty value.

That's why I insist you go with `NotNull` for your requirements.

**B)**

Also I can think of another way to handle that.

```
@Component
public class AppConfig {

    @Value("${property1}")
    private String property1;

    @Value("${property2}")     
    private String property2; 
}
```

Using injection with `@Value`, spring will fail to initialize the singleton AppConfig during application startup if some property with exactly the same name does not exist on properties file, therefore you will be informed that no property with that name exists and the application will not start up.

Comment: 'You can't say I want it to be able to be nullable but also the validator should complain when that property is null.' - the property being `null` and the property being misspelled are two different cases, though. The latter means detecting that a property could not be bound to any `@ConfigurationProperties` bean and is, to my taste, a reasonable expectation

Comment: The only possible way of detecting a property been misspelled is to be null. How else could you know if it is misspelled? So my suggestion is use null to find out misspelled properties and empty strings as properties that exist but don't have a value. Just my 2 cents.

Comment: @crizzis Spring does not know what all properties are in application.yaml. They are just key value pairs. It loads everything on context and later uses what it needs to use. It does not know what it needs to use and where when it loads the properties

Comment: 'The only possible way of detecting a property been misspelled is to be null' - umm, not really. Another possible way of detecting a property is misspelled is detecting that the property does not match any of the properties defined in the property schemas generated by `spring-boot-configuration-processor`, for example. In theory, you could use those files to validate the YAML files. In practice, usually your IDE does that for you by highlighting unrecognized properties as warnings

Comment: In this specific case with `@Configuration @ConfigurationProperties` and a class containing only fields IDEA will not catch the error. If you check my solution B then it is much easier and you don't have to implement anything extra. My A explanation was for the specific case of OP with `@Configuration @ConfigurationProperties` class.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by IDEA [not catching the error](https://imgur.com/a/ChaP6SR), but B doesn't answer the original question, which was: 'Is there a way to validate application.properties (or yml) if the properties match Java bean **that it is mapped to via @ConfigurationProperties**'

Answer (score 0):

You can specify `ignoreUnknownFields = false` to ensure that no unknown properties are defined under the corresponding `prefix`. ([docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.7.2/api/org/springframework/boot/context/properties/ConfigurationProperties.html#ignoreUnknownFields--)):

> Flag to indicate that when binding to this object unknown fields should be ignored. An unknown field could be a sign of a mistake in the Properties.

Borrowing from your example:

```java
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "myapp", ignoreUnknownFields = false)
public class AppConfig {
    private String property1;     
    private String property2;
}
```

This means `myapp.property1` and `myapp.property2` are allowed but not required to be set, so they remain nullable.
Any other set property with the `myapp` prefix (such as `myapp.properrrrrty2=2`) will cause a startup failure and the offending property name will be logged in the exception.